# Gradle C (native) task output file/files (to be used in other tasks/projects)

Tags: c++, c, gradle, native

Using the c plugin, one can specify executables and libraries.
I'm using a string tag to specify a library with an OS specific name (later used in a JNI setup).

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.SystemUtils as SU

buildscript {
        repositories {
                mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
                classpath 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2'
        }
}

def osString = SU.IS_OS_LINUX ? "linux" : (SU.IS_OS_MAC_OSX ? "macosx" : SU.IS_OS_WINDOWS ? "windows" : "")
assert osString
```

That is to get the OS string. Here the declaration of the library:

```
libraries {
    "diaf-${osString}" {}
}
```

When running

> gradle tasks

on a linux box, one of the tasks will be "diaf-linuxSharedLibrary"

**How does one get a handle to the output file of the task (to be used in another task)?** In this case libdiaf-linux.so?
Without resorting to hard coded paths as in

> def path = "${buildDir}/build/binaries/diaf-linuxSharedLibrary/libdiaf-linux.so"

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the libraries are always created under the same location - see [here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/nativeBinaries.html#N15C7C) for the details - You need to hardcode only part of the path.

Unfortunately I haven't tested it - don't know how, to be honest.

**EDIT**

Below you can find a sample script (created after digging through gradle sources), that prints tasks and output files. I see that building native libraries is organised completely different than other plugins. Hopes it helped you somehow:

```
apply plugin: 'c'

libraries {
    hello {}
}

binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinarySpec) { 
   println it.sharedLibraryFile
   println it.tasks
}

binaries.withType(StaticLibraryBinarySpec) { 
   println it.staticLibraryFile
   println it.tasks
}
```

You can also find some sample under `$GRADLE_HOME/samples/native-binaries/`.

Comment: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskOutputs.html
Looking for something similar to be used in native libraries/executable tasks

Comment: Yes, I know about task outputs and also was looking for something like that - but haven't found. Will also have a look later on. But as you can see for given component name it's not difficult to construct the output file: `${project.buildDir}/binaries/${component.name}Executable/${component.name}`

Comment: Hard coding paths...
`tasks.findByName("diaf-${osString}SharedLibrary").outputs.hasOutput` returns false.
`tasks.findByName("diaf-${osString}SharedLibrary").output.files.files` returns zero array.
So, it seems like the C plugin doesn't declare output files. Bug?

Comment: It seems that it isn't, I was trying in the same way, but I wouldn't say that this is a bug. Maybe it just works in a different manner.

Comment: `SharedLibrary` and `StaticLibrary` tasks are *lifecycle tasks* - such task does not define outputs but is a kind of task that is used to define dependency on it. For instance `check` from `java` plugin task is a kind of such task.

Comment: Ok, then to find which sub-task publishes the output files then. linkDiaf-linuxSharedLibrary?

Comment: Found it -
`tasks.findByName("linkDiaf-${osString}SharedLibrary").outputs.files.files` is an array of two java.lang.File objects, one the output directory and the last one the actual .so file.

Comment: Marked your edited answer as the answer for it also gives the File to the output binaries.